# SELECT all items in common between two users on FOUR tables

Tags: mysql

I have now four tables:

item_to_list (to store the relations between list and item)

```
| item_to_list_id | list_id |  item_id |
-----------------------------------------
```

item_tb

```
| item_id | item_name |
-----------------------
```

list_tb (is a list of items that belong to a unique user, a list can't be owned by two users)

```
| list_id | list_name | user_id |
---------------------------------
```

user_tb

```
| user_id | user_name |..etc..
-------------------------------
```

An item can belong to one or more list.

A list can belong to only one user and a user can have one or more lists...

Different lists can have same items in common (think a grocery list that you buy every week the same items)

basically imagine my website is an e-commerce, the list is an order, and i want to know how many items two users (which i know the name and id) have in  common  have bought in their entire experience in my website....

**So, given the user_id = A and user_id = B how can I do a mysql query to select all the items the belong both to user A and user B?**

*note: I wrote a similar question but was about three tables not four. And i'm learnign a lot doing these progressive questions thanks!!!*

**UPDATE: my bad wrote a wrong table name, now is correct**

Comment: I answered on your 3 join table, but what is the relationship of the LIST table and items... no such element shown to complete relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Ill answer in pseudo code hope you understand,basicly idea is create a set of user A items and join it by item_id with set of user B items.

Obviously to generate user A and user B items you need same query with different where clause.

```
    Select A.item_id from 
    (select user A items) as A 
    join (select user B items ) as B 
    on A.item_id=B.item_id
```

I hope you can create `select user X items` query

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is getting all of the items a user has ever bought. This is quite easy using `item_to_list`:

```
SELECT item_id FROM item_to_list WHERE user_id = A;
```

However, keeping `user_id` inside both `item_to_list` and `list_tb` leads to lots of data duplication. (Google relational database normalisation for fun stuff on this). So I would remove the `user_id` field from `item_to_list` and rely on `list_tb` to store this information.

The query then becomes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id
    FROM item_to_list AS itl, list_tb AS ltb
    WHERE ltb.user_id = A
    AND ltb.list_id = itl.list_id;
```

This is assuming that your `item_to_list.item_to_user_id` is the same as the `item_tb.list_tb`

At this point you can generate a table containing a list of all of the items ever bought by a user. Now the problem becomes generating a table for user A and a table for user B and then comparing the results.

```
SELECT itl.item_id
    FROM item_to_list AS aitl, list_tb AS altb
    WHERE altb.user_id = A
    AND altb.list_id = aitl.list_id;
    AND aitl.item_id IN
        SELECT DISTINCT item_id
            FROM item_to_list AS bitl, list_tb AS bltb
            WHERE bltb.user_id = B
            AND bltb.list_id = bitl.list_id;
```

Note: This is thouroughly untested :) and there may well be improvements to be made with regards to efficiency.

EDIT: Completed answer

Comment: btw I made a mistake on my question: the first table doesn't have the user_id in it as you correctly said. thanks!

Comment: exactly the first thought was: I select all the items that user A bought, then the items user B bought, then intersect the result to see which and how many items they bought so far...I would optimized with one query only instead of using php right?